# Probabilistic Proof for Turan's Theorem

Tags: probability, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

I was referring [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_conditional_probabilities#Tur.C3.A1n.27s_theorem) proof for Turan's Theorem. But I am not very sure about the correctness (or my understanding) of the proof, specifically the part where they claim the probability of selecting a vertex as $$p(u) \ge \frac{1}{d(u)+1}$$

The issue is that with this inequality, the probabilities may add up to greater than 1. For example consider the following graph

[image: Graph]

Here we will get $$\sum_{u}p(u) = p(1) + p(2) + p(3) \ge \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} > 1$$

So is this proof incorrect?

Comment: If the events are not mutually exclusive then their probabilities can add up to more than one. For instance, toss a coin 10 times. The probability of heads on the first toss is 1/2, the probability of heads on the second toss is 1/2, etc.; these probabilities add up to 5, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That proof is a bit informal. What you add, are not probabilities, but expected values, which happen to be equal to the probabilities, and the author of the proof didn't want to dwell too much on this. If you want to make it more formal, define:

$$X_u = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if }u \in S, \\0 & \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Observe that $\mathbb{E}X_u = \mathbb{P}(u \in S) \geq \frac{1}{\deg(u)+1}$ and thus, by linearity of expectation

$$\mathbb{E}|S| = \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_u X_u\right)=\sum_u\mathbb{E}X_u\geq\sum_u\frac{1}{\deg(u)+1}.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

**Edit:** Regarding the comment, with the standard greedy algorithm the equality would be incorrect. Sometimes you can include $u$ in $S$ even if some of its neighbors were checked earlier in the permutation, but were not picked because of their neighbors. For example, take a path consisting of four vertices $v_0 \leftrightarrow v_1 \leftrightarrow v_2 \leftrightarrow v_3$ and calculate $P(v_2 \in S)$ given the permutation:

\begin{align}
\langle v_2, *, *, *\rangle &\to 6 \times 1 \\
\langle v_0, v_2, *, *\rangle &\to 2 \times 1 \\
\langle *, v_2, *, *\rangle &\to 4 \times 0 \\
\langle v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3\rangle &\to 1 \times 1 \\
\langle v_0, v_3, v_2, v_1\rangle &\to 1 \times 0 \\
\langle *, *, v_2, *\rangle &\to 4 \times 0 \\
\langle *, *, *, v_2\rangle &\to 6 \times 0
\end{align}

which gives $\frac{9}{24} > \frac{8}{24} = \frac{1}{\deg(v_2)+1}$.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! Also I was thinking that $P(u \in S) = \frac{1}{deg(u) + 1}$ instead of $P(u \in S)\ge \frac{1}{deg(u) + 1}$. So what I was wondering is whether we actually have equality and we have taken the greater than equal to sign just for convenience or is the equality incorrect?

Comment: @BanachTarski The equalities would be incorrect, see the edit.